# recursion in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

i Want to genrate possible combination with particluar no in sql server 2005 recursively.

e.g

we Have Main No 2 and Sub no 4,5,6
Combination are

```
2 4
2 5
2 6
4 5
4 6
5 6
5 2 
...........like combination.
```

Thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @T table (Num int)
insert into @T values (2)
insert into @T values (4)
insert into @T values (5)
insert into @T values (6)

select
  T1.Num as Num1,
  T2.Num as Num2
from @T as T1
  cross join @T as T2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;With
  List AS (SELECT 2 AS y UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6)
SELECT 
   *
FROM
   List CROSS JOIN list
```

You'd generate list from your tables

Comment: what no are not fixed like 2,3,4,5 every time it is flexiable.

Comment: @user654848: Please edit your question to add other examples for us to have the idea of how 'flexible' it may be, if you'd like to have a more universal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the numbers in TempTable and use Cross Join

```
Create Table #LeftTemp
(   ID int,
)

Create Table #RightTemp
(   ID int,
)

-- Write insert statements

Select * from #LeftTemp CROSS JOIN #RightTemp
```